# Drawing SysML/UML diagrams in javascript

Tags: javascript, d3.js, drawing, uml, sysml

I have to  write an application in javascript using the d3 graphics library to display SysML diagrams. I feel like most of this project is within my grasp but I have no idea how to approach one aspect of it.

Since the application will assume nothing about the complexity, size, or nesting of the diagram, hard-coding rules for how to arrange the blocks would be futile. I imagine significant study has gone into this kind of thing before but I am unaware of what it would fall under or where to look.

Also, does anyone know where to find examples of SysML diagrams in XML format? Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Since SysML is a UML2 profile, you might find [jsUML2](http://www.uco.es/~in1rosaj/tool_jsUML2.html) a useful starting point for your attempts.  Basically you could use the jsUML2 to draw the SysML diagram and then use the export function to produce the XML.  NB:  XMI is the standard for interchange between different tools.